# Docker Express Node.js app container not connecting with MongoDB container giving error TransientTransactionError

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, express, docker-compose

I am under a weird dilemma. I have created a node application and this application needs to connect to MongoDB (through docker container) I created a `docker-compose` file as follows:

```
version: "3"
services:
  mongo:
     image: mongo
     expose:
      - 27017
     volumes:
      - ./data/db:/data/db

  my-node:
    image: "<MY_IMAGE_PATH>:latest"
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    working_dir: /opt/app
    ports:
      - "2000:2000"
    volumes:
      - ./mod:/usr/app
    networks:
      - webnet
    command: "node app.js"
networks:
  webnet:
```

I am using mongo official image. I have ommited my docker image from the above configuration .I have set up with many configuration but i am unable to connect to mongoDB (yes i have changed the `MongoDB` uri inside the node.js application too). but whenever i am `deploying` my `docker-compose` my application on start up gives me always `MongoNetworkError` of `TransientTransactionError`. I am unable to understand where is the problem since many hours.

One more weird thing is when i running my docker-compose file i receive following logs:

```
Creating network server_default
Creating network server_webnet
Creating service server_mongo
Creating service server_feed-grabber
```

Could it be that both services are in a different network? If yes then how to fix that?

Other Info:

- In node.js application MongoDB uri that i tried is
  `mongodb://mongo:27017/MyDB`
- I am running my docker-compose with the command: `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml server`
- My node.js image is Ubuntu 18

Anyone can help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok So i have tried few things and i figured out at last after spending many many hours. There were two things i was doing wrong and they were hitting me on last point:

1. First thing logging of the startup of docker showed me that it was creating two networks `server_default` and `server_webnet` this is the first mistake. Both containers should be in the same network while working.
2. The second thing I needed to run the Mongo container first as my Node.js application `depend_on` the Mongo container to be run first. This is exactly what I did in my docker-compose configuration by introducing `depend_on` property.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was:

1- get your ip by running command

> docker-machine ip

2- don't go to localhost/port, go to your ip/port, example : http://192.168.99.100:8080